# Flask: iterable expected, not InstanceState

Tags: python, csv, sqlalchemy

I'm just trying to look through a queryset of objects and write to a csv export:

```
@expose('/csv-export')
def csv_export(self):
    batch_num = request.args.get('batch_num')

    if not batch_num:
        flash('Invalid batch id', 'danger')
        abort(404)

    si = io.StringIO()
    cw = csv.writer(si)

    # array
    my_objects = MyObject.query.filter_by(batch_num=batch_num).all()

    row_headers = my_objects[0].serialize()
    cw.writerow(row_headers)

    object_rows = []
    for my_object in my_objects:
        for k, v in vars(my_object).items():
            object_rows.append(v)

    cw.writerows(object_rows)
    output = make_response(si.getvalue())
    output.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=export.csv"
    output.headers["Content-type"] = "text/csv"
    return output
```

If I inspect what `object_rows` is it looks like this:

```
[<sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x7f92a791a390>, 2, None, '3312363552684', 551, None, '24daae41-82f5-42bf-b12f-9762554ee394', <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x7f92a791a588>,   ]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
for my_object in my_objects:
        for k, v in vars(my_object).items():
            object_rows.append(v)
```

SQLAlchemy creates an attribute on each instance of an instrumented ORM object called `_sa_instance_state` which is used by SQLAlchemy internally. When you iterate over the object’s `__dict__` using `vars()` this key/value pair is traversed along with all other attribute key/values.

So the solution is to filter it out. A common way to do this is to filter keys out based on whether they start with a leading underscore, e.g:

```
for my_object in my_objects:
        for k, v in vars(my_object).items():
            if not k.startswith(‘_’):
                object_rows.append(v)
```

This will filter out all private attributes but you can be more specific with your filtering if there are other private attribute values that you want to capture.